# Is there a way to see when the last time an uninstalled app was installed?

Tags: applications

Here's the situation, I'm trying to work things out with an ex, but her friend saw me on Bumble and told her. I haven't used the app since before her and I started dating, but I must have just deleted the app without ever deleting my profile. It's been uninstalled for well over a year. Is there a way to see the last time an uninstalled app was installed so I can show her that I have not been using it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The information you're seeking is located inside the *library.db* which is located at */data/data/com.android.vending/databases*. It is part of Google Play Store app's data.

**Note**: I presupposed that the app was installed via Play Store, as otherwise, this solution is of no use.

### For an unrooted Android

- Use [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to pull data of *com.android.vending* (Google Play Store)

  ```
    adb backup com.android.vending
  ```
- convert the backup into tar file using [Android Backup Extractor (ABE)](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) or other means you know of.

  (ABE needs [Java Runtime Environment](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) and has *README.txt* for usage). ABE would unpack the `.ab` file into a `.tar` which you can then extract using an archiver like Ark, 7zip, WinRAR.)
- Locate the *library.db* under databases directory and use an Sqlite viewer software (such as [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)) to open that file.
- Search for the package name of your uninstalled app (*com.bumble.app* in OP's case) under the *doc_id* column, and note down the corresponding timestamp in the *purchase_time* column in that same entry. That is a unix timestamp. Furthermore, a free app is also considered purchased (for zero amount) in this table, so do not be confused by the column name.
- Use a site like [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to convert the timestamp into human readable form.

### For a rooted Android

You can use an SQlite viewer app to view that database. I used MyAndroidTools (not available on Play Store anymore) for testing purposes.

Comment: The `backup.ab` that the first command created for me was only 47 bytes large and hence useless. Did something in Android change that broke this procedure or this particular to my phone?

Comment: @MrArsGravis I do not know the exact reason why adb backup failed to work. I don't use Google Play anymore so I can't test my own answer either. A couple of issues related to adb backup created X bytes backup can be found under the search query [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=adb+bytes). You could also ask a new question if none of them addresses your problem.