# Find Exact Install Date of A FREE App From The PlayStore On A Older Phone

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-play-games, clash-of-clans

I'm looking to find the instillation date of an app I had on my old phone.
I've tried looking on the play store  [here](https://play.google.com/store/account)  however it only shows be previous paid purchases.

I've also tried using a android emulator on my pc to view Google Play Games achievements, as it appeared it used to show you the time those achievements are unlocked, however checking it now just shows the achievements and not the times.

EDIT: To clarify the app is no longer installed, hence all answers in the other question are worthless as this is not the same question, as these only answer the question to when the app was installed on the current device, not when they were installed on another phone but are still linked to the account.

Comment: See if this is what helps your case than: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/196543/96277

Comment: @Firelord thanks but that only works for a phone you still have access to, I'm looking to find it from googles own data.